# How can I make a machine where when I press a button, it plays a specific record?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I want a jukebox type thing where I have a list of buttons that when pressed, play a certain song. I can use command blocks if they are needed.

So far I have tried to use droppers to place disks into jukeboxes but I can't figure out how that really works.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the `/playsound` command. The syntax is:

```
/playsound <sound> <source> <player> [x] [y] [z] [volume] [pitch] [minimumVolume]
```

With it, you can play a record like this:

```
/playsound record.cat record @a
```

---

- `sound` is the name of the sound event to play; [here's a list](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json#Sound_events).
- `source` determines which slider on <kbd>Music & Sound Options</kbd> will affect the sound's volume.
- `player` is a selector determining who the sound will be played to.
- `x y z` are the coordinates of the sound's origin (louder the closer you are to it)
- `volume` is how loud the sound is (over 1 has no effect for this), and how far away it can be heard from.
- `pitch` is the pitch of the sound, between 0 and 2 (lower than 0.5 has no effect)
- `minimumVolume` is the volume the sound plays to for anyone who's too far away to hear the sound normally.

Comment: So if I want it to play a song through the jukebox/noteblocks category, what would I put for the source?

Comment: @Mattmontan The possible sources, which you can see with tab-complete, are: 

`master` ("Master Volume"), 
`ambient` ("Ambient/Environment"), 
`block` ("Blocks"), 
`hostile` ("Hostile Creatures"), 
`music` ("Music"), 
`neutral` ("Friendly Creatures"), 
`player` ("Players"), 
`record` ("Jukebox/Note Blocks"), 
`voice` ("Voice/Speech"), 
`weather` ("Weather").

The `record` source, as used in the example command in the answer, is for the "Jukebox/Note Blocks" category.